# Was the physical resemblance between the singer "Mrs. Hobby" and Lillian Gorfein deliberate?

Tags: inside-llewyn-davis

Was the physical resemblance between the singer "Mrs. Hobby" and Lillian Gorfein deliberate in *Inside Llewyn Davis*? They were both women of the same age and body type — indeed, both were singers. It seems to me that Mrs. Hobby may have been verbally attacked so viciously (that was really a terrible heckle, well deserving of a beating) by LD ironically out of guilt for having been so nasty to Lillian.

It further seems to show that LD, despite trying to help the cat, was basically a bully, only threatening to people who could not fight back — indeed: He abandons an unconscious, handicapped junky in a car (this man may well have died), is willing to get into a physical altercation not only with the handicapped junky but with his agent (over the coat), an extremely old man, as well as the two harmless women. LD is not taking the gradual realization that he will not make it as a folk musician (and how many people do) very well.